# WindowsAzureStorage version 9.3.0 throws exception method not found when referenced in .NetFramework based project

Tags: c#, azure

I have.NetStandardProject which has code to query CosmosDB Table API when I reference this project into the .NetFramework based project I am getting follwoing execeptption while calling the method.

Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableContinuationToken)'

Answer (score 0):

Referencing a .NET Standard assembly from a .NET Framework project used to not work, but support for doing just that was added in .NET 4.6.1.

Unfortunately, it's a pretty flaky feature and it sometimes **requires assembly binding redirects** that need to be generated during the build process.

While the project properties dialog has an option to auto-generate binding redirects, this has no effect for libraries so you need to edit the `.csproj file` manually to include:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For more details and explanations, you could refer to the GitHub issue [Issues with .NET Standard 2.0 with .NET Framework & NuGet](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/31) and this [one](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481).

BTW, you should ensure your .net standard version correspond with .net framework. Here is a [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) you could read.